# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/MessageTag

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am updating Spring framework from version 3.0 to version 4.3. Working on Portlet Development using IBM Websphere and Using ANT not Maven. I have checked the classpath and it contains the class file of MessageTag. In previous version(3.0) MessageTag was in package Web.Servlet and now in this version(4.3) this class is in package webmvc. The package name is same.

But I am getting the following error message everytime I try and run the portal.

```
[10/18/16 10:28:52:533 EDT] 00000039 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /themes/html/Default.jsp in application XXX. Exception created : com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/MessageTag
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:695)
at com.ibm._jsp._Default._jspService(_Default.java:1610)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1658)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:940)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:503)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:711)
at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.handleRequest(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:93)
at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.include(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:53)
at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:50)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.themes.Default.doDispatch(Default.java:294)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.themes.Default.render(Default.java:247)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.ThemeTemplate.render(ThemeTemplate.java:65)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPRenderPhase.processRendering(WPRenderPhase.java:504)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPBaseRenderPhase.execute(WPBaseRenderPhase.java:248)
at com.ibm.wps.state.phases.AbstractRenderPhase.next(AbstractRenderPhase.java:106)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPAbstractRenderPhase.next(WPAbstractRenderPhase.java:100)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.callPortal(Servlet.java:959)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:681)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doFilter(Servlet.java:1433)
at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerCleanup.doFilter(ContentHandlerCleanup.java:672)
at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:93)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.service(Servlet.java:1421)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1658)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1598)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtensionFilter$ExtendedFilterChain.doFilter(ExtensionFilter.java:91)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtensionFilter.doFilter(ExtensionFilter.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtendedLocaleFilter.doFilter(ExtendedLocaleFilter.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
at com.ibm.wps.resolver.friendly.servlet.FriendlySelectionFilter.doFilter(FriendlySelectionFilter.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
at com.ibm.wps.mappingurl.impl.URLAnalyzer.doFilter(URLAnalyzer.java:448)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
at com.ibm.wps.engine.VirtualPortalFilter.doFilter(VirtualPortalFilter.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
at com.ibm.wps.state.filter.StateCleanup.doFilter(StateCleanup.java:95)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:935)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:503)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:875)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/MessageTag
at com.ibm._jsp._Default._jspx_meth_s_message_2(_Default.java:2670)
at com.ibm._jsp._Default._jspService(_Default.java:637)
... 71 more

[10/18/16 10:31:43:025 EDT] 00000043 webcontainer  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /seedlist/server has not been defined.
```

I saw some posts regarding this and they said I need to update web.xml by adding 'el-ignored' tag. But this also did not work.

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
           <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <el-ignored>true</el-ignored>                            
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Can someone help me with this. Also, if there is any more info required do let me know. Thanks! :)

Comment: have you changed all the dependencies from version 3 to 4. Also you added all required dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I have. But it turns out, I had not checked if the libraries were added in WEB-INF folder and that was the issue. But Thanks!